# How can I prevent to_yaml from double quoting my key and value when using $ or .. in a YAML hash?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
yml_hash = {'$ref': '..path/to_file'}.deep_stringify_keys
```

When I call `File.open(ROOT_FILE_PATH, 'w') { |file| file.write(yml_hash.to_yaml) }` I see an entry in the resulting yml file that looks like this:

```
"$ref": "..path/to_file"
```

I want it to look like this:

```yaml
'$ref': ..path/to_file
```

All of my other stringified keys and values work correctly

I tried removing the $ symbol from the key and the .. from the value. This removed the double quotes. Is there a way to remove the double quotes and produce the desired output?

Comment: The dollar sign has a special meaning in YAML (it indicates a scalar). Therefore, it is correct that it is wrapped with quotes. Why do you care about how the keys and values are represented in YAML? Do you have issue with reading the YAML later on?

Comment: @spickermann. Thank you for replying. Yes. I need to write my yml to a file with the expected format '$ref': ..path/to_file

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes. Just updated my code. Thanks. The post is correct now

Comment: This is due to the implementation of the emitter in the `Psych` library.